# How to get JSon from server to ListView?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I want to retrieve my all data from database but there is a compilation error and I am new with android. This is my class in which I want to get all users from table and show there name in listview. If there is no name in then username will be the name. Error that I am getting is Frame not available.

```
package com.gmakerorganisation.glocator.Fragments;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.gmakerorganisation.glocator.Config;
import com.gmakerorganisation.glocator.GetAllUsers;
import com.gmakerorganisation.glocator.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Sendrequest extends Fragment {
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UserList;
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "profile";

    ListView listView;
    public Sendrequest() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sendrequest, container, false);
        listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        new GetStudents().execute();

        return v;
    }

    private class GetStudents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        // Hashmap for ListView

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            GetAllUsers webreq = new GetAllUsers();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(Config.USERS_URL, GetAllUsers.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            UserList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
            li * */

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), UserList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_PHONE}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.mobile});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ParseJSON(String json) {
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                // Hashmap for ListView
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray userrs = jsonObj.getJSONArray(null);

                // looping through All Students
                for (int i = 0; i < userrs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = userrs.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                    String profile = c.getString(TAG_PROFILE);



                    // tmp hashmap for single student
                    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    user.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    user.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    user.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    user.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                    user.put(TAG_PROFILE, profile);

                    // adding student to students list
                    studentList.add(user);
                }
                return studentList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

GetAllUser class

```
package com.gmakerorganisation.glocator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by user on 14-07-2016.
 */
public class GetAllUsers {
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    //Constructor with no parameter
    public GetAllUsers() {

    }

    /**
     * Making web service call
     *
     * @url - url to make request
     * @requestmethod - http request method
     */
    public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod) {
        return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     *
     * @url - url to make request
     * @requestmethod - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     */
    public String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod,
                                     HashMap<String, String> params) {
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urladdress);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            if (requestmethod == POST) {
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } else if (requestmethod == GET) {
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            }

            if (params != null) {
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                boolean first = true;
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    else
                        result.append("&");

                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    result.append("=");
                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
                }

                writer.write(result.toString());

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

My php source code is

```
<?php 

//If a post request is detected 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


    //Importing the dbConnect script 
    require_once('conn.php');

    $users = array();

            $sql = "SELECT id , username, name, phone, profile FROM glocator";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $users['id'] = $row['id'];
                $users['username'] = $row['username'];
                $users['name'] = $row['name'];
                $users['phone'] = $row['phone'];
                $users['profile'] = $row['profile'];

             echo json_encode($users);
            }
        }


    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

And I am using postman so when I send post request it gives this data

```
{"id":"1","username":"gmaker","name":"SHUBHAM SHARMA","phone":"9711979977","profile":"http:\/\/glocator.esy.es\/profilepicture\/1."}{"id":"4","username":"somnath","name":"","phone":"9582223881","profile":""}{"id":"7","username":"shitij","name":"","phone":"9650154839","profile":""}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Your json structure is wrong

Comment: json wrong . copy and paste json here http://jsonprettyprint.com/

Answer (score 2):

You json have some errors, copy your JSON and verify here.

Its must looks like:

```
[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "username":"gmaker",
    "name":"SHUBHAM SHARMA",
    "phone":"9711979977",
    "profile":"http:\/\/glocator.esy.es\/profilepicture\/1."
    },
    {
    "id":"4",
    "username":"somnath",
    "name":"",
    "phone":"9582223881",
    "profile":""
    },
    {
    "id":"7",
    "username":"shitij",
    "name":"",
    "phone":"9650154839",
    "profile":""
    }
]
```

Now you can follow some following tutorials.

[Android json parsing using okhttp example with new material design library](http://www.pratikbutani.com/2015/12/android-json-parsing-using-okhttp-example-with-new-material-design-library/)

Answer (score 0):

your Json file does not contain any array.Then you could not use it to retrieve data by creating object of jsonarray..so try this code and remove for loop.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

// looping through All Students
JSONObject c = JSONObject.getJSONObject(jsonobj);

String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
String profile = c.getString(TAG_PROFILE);
```